How do I make \leftmark reference the chapter I'm in?
Right now I'm writing down a cookbook and I would want the header of my book to crossreference the chapter I'm in, but I simply do not know how; I'll give you now the code I'm trying to make work:
\documentclass[16pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, hyperref}

\begin{document}

    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhead{} 
    \fancyhead[L]{\footnotesize \hy\nouppercase{\href{\chapter}{\leftmark}\hfill}}
    \fancyhead[R]{\footnotesize Mi nombresico}
    
\end{document}

This code doesn't make \leftmark crossreference the chapter. How do I solve this?
Edit: I'm going to explain it another way. The code I have is the following:
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhead{} 
    \fancyhead[L]{\footnotesize \nouppercase{\leftmark\hfill}}
    \fancyhead[R]{\footnotesize Navarro Bonanad, Rubén}
\end{document}

I'd like for the \leftmark to crossreference what it is showing (e.g.: in this case the chapter it is in). I've tried simply putting it inside of \cref so the relevant line would look like: \fancyhead[L]{\footnotesize \nouppercase{\cref{\leftmark}\hfill}} but it doesn't work like I imagined it would (to redirect you to the start of the chapter in this case).

"Whatever chapter I want" is a lot harder than "the current chapter".  Could you extend your example to actually create a chapter?

Please note that standard LaTeX classes like book don't put a header on the first page of the chapter.  And once you have added a \chapter command, \leftmark should contain the chapter title, and also the chapter number in the default case, so you shouldn't add \thechapteryourself. And anyway,\hrefshould have a URL as argument, not\thechapter`.

welcome! off-topic: book doesn't support 16pt. you are effectively using 10pt.

@Teepeemm I want the solution for "the current chapter", I'm sorry for being wrong when stating my question! I always try to generalise things (so later I can reuse them, but this time it backfired!). Could you show me the solution?

Could you add the chapter command to your example?  And to follow up on Pieter's comment, you need a second page in the chapter before you can expect the \leftmark to appear.  And are you wanting that href to take you to the beginning of the chapter?

@Teepeemm I thought the chapter was a Latex defined comman, similar to \thesection or 'thesubsection', that's why I didn't define it. Maybe that is what's causing the problem! Indeed, I already knew that you need a second page for \leftmark to appear, and in the book in which I use it, I do have multiple pages inside each chapter. To your final question my answer is yes, I do want the href to take me to the begging of the chapeter

\chapter is indeed defined by the book class.  My remark is that you aren't using \chapter in your example, so you're leaving it up to us to guess why it's not working.  At the moment, it looks like Pieter has identified the problem in that you're not using href correctly.  But since no one (including you) can expect the code you've posted to possibly work, we can't know that we've identified the problem.

I've changed it to \chapter instead of \thechapter. I supose the problem is the \href, but now my question is: What should I put if not \href?

We are asking you to use \chapter at least once in your documment and use placeholder test to obtain at least a second page. Your MWE is supposed to make easy for us to help you but is lacking key features to show us your problem

@Mane32 You've responded to me and it works out. I'm really sorry for the MWE not compiling. It is still my second question in the forum and still don't know perfectly how to state my questions correctly. I'll take it into account for any questions I make from now on.

Your MWE doesn't compile for me, and it lacked chapter entries. I removed the \hy command, replaced the \href, and added two chapter for testing. Beware that your 16pt options is not supported by book class.
This solution does the trick automatically but I haven't tested in more complex documents:
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
    
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhead{} 
    \fancyhead[L]{\footnotesize \nouppercase{\hyperlink{chapter.\thechapter}{\leftmark}\hfill}}
    \fancyhead[R]{\footnotesize Mi nombresico}
    
    \chapter{This chapter}
    
    \lipsum
    
    \chapter{This other chapter}
    
    \lipsum
\end{document}

Another solution requires you to add manually a \label{chap\thechapter} after each chapter.
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
    
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhead{} 
    \fancyhead[L]{\footnotesize \nouppercase{\hyperref[chap\thechapter]{\leftmark}\hfill}}
    \fancyhead[R]{\footnotesize Mi nombresico}
    
    \chapter{This chapter}\label{chap\thechapter}
    
    \lipsum
    
    \chapter{This other chapter}\label{chap\thechapter}
    
    \lipsum
\end{document}

